# Setting up a TCP server on gazebo ::Unable to use the gazebo::transport::Conection::listen() function

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am a beginner on gazebo I am trying to figure out how to use the gazebo::transport::Connection::Listen() function

Im unable to understand how to write the accept callback function I would be grateful if any one could post an example or guide me on how to write the accept callback function What ive written so far is :
//In the load function
transport::ConnectionPtr IMUcomm;
IMUcomm  = transport::ConnectionPtr(new transport::Connection);
IMUcomm->Listen(30000,acceptME);

//Outside the load but in the gazebo namespace
void acceptME(const transport::ConnectionPtr& comm)
{}

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7659/setting-up-a-tcp-server-on-gazebo-::unable-to-use-the-gazebo::transport::conection::listen()-function/) by [Mohnish](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1051/mohnish/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 23 on 2014-12-09

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Gazebo's Connection class is fairly low level, and not intended for direct use outside of Gazebo.

Here are some [tutorials on using Gazebo's transport mechanisms](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=transport).

There is also [publisher example code](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/3739fec9beb34c2111ad4d48a4f12e132b684426/examples/stand_alone/publisher/?at=default), and [subscriber example code](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/3739fec9beb34c2111ad4d48a4f12e132b684426/examples/stand_alone/listener/?at=default)

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2014-12-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mohnish](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1051/mohnish/) on 2014-12-12**:
Then what do you suggest I should use to communicate with a program that is running the mission control code (Written in java) via TCP/IP

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2014-12-16**:
I believe [zeromq](http://zeromq.org/) has a java interface.